# How can I test a method that logs to the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I want to test this method that logs (either to console.error, or a logger you pass in) properly.

```
/**
 * Logs access errors in a way that is easy to quickly decipher the endpoint that was hit and the error that was received
 *
 * This was inspired from axios recommendation on handling errors https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors
 *
 * @param {Object | String} err      The error we want to log
 * @param {Object} [logger=console]  An optional logger which defaults to console
 * @public
 * @since 5.3.0
 */
function logAxiosErr(err, logger = console) {
  if (err.response) {
    const error = {
      error: `${err.response.status} - "${err.response.data}" with ${err.config.method.toUpperCase()} ${err.config.url}`,
      headers: err.config.headers,
      payload: err.config.data
    }
    // The request was made and the server responded with a status code that falls out of the range of 2xx
    logger.error(error)
  } else if (err.request) {
    // The request was made but no response was received
    // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
    // http.ClientRequest in node.js
    logger.error(err.request)
  } else if (err.message) {
    // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
    logger.error(err.message)
  } else {
    logger.error(err)
  }
```

This test obviously doesn't test anything. How can I improve it to actually test that what was logged is what I'm expecting?

```
describe('#logAxiosError', () => {
    it('should log a string error ', () => {
      const err = 'SOME ERROR'
      expect(utils.logAxiosErr(err))
    })
})
```

Comment: Not directly answering your question but why not test the `err.message` property in `throw Error(msg)` ? I think it's must more accurate in observing behavior and actually testing the message of the output.

Comment: I could to that too. I don't think it matters in this case though. Either way it's an object with a property message.

Comment: You've set that up so you can inject your own logger, so why not use that?

Comment: Check Sinon spies: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's as far as i knew how to write it for unit testing. I know i need to inject a logger, but not sure how to finish writing this test so that I can run assertions.

Comment: What would you inject if not some kind of test double?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm very anti-test double. I believe in dependency injection instead of using test doubles.

Comment: That stance makes absolutely no sense. One of the *points* of dependency injection is that you can easily provide test doubles, those things aren't mutually exclusive at all.

Comment: Sorry i thought you were referring to something like this https://github.com/testdouble which is like proxyquire which is used to overwrite your deps rather than have them injected

Answer (score 3):

One way to test dependency is to create a spy object (if using jasmine) for logger and pass it to logAxiosErr and then verify expectations on the spy object. So in your test above

```
describe('#logAxiosError', () => {
    it('should log a string error ', () => {
    const err = 'SOME ERROR'
    var logger = jasmine.createSpyObj('logger', ['error']);
    utils.logAxiosErr(err, logger);
    expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(err);
  })
})
```

Comment: This is definitely an option (and i still might use it), but i was hoping for an option that was more pure and didn't require spies. Maybe that's not possible?

Comment: @Catfish what does *"pure"* mean?

Comment: Well one time i wrote (With much help) a logger method and the unit tests created a stream and actually read the output of the stream. I would consider that a more pure solution since it doesn't use spies. TBH it was a lot of work and maybe spies are the better solution.

Comment: Spies don't allow me to assert the actual value that was logged

Comment: @Adi that is not the pure way to do it. I should be able to write a test and pass in a logger and then assert the output of that logger.

Comment: The purpose of unit test is to validate that a unit performs as designed. In unit test for logAxiosErr you should verify that different branches of if are executed as expected and logger.error is called with correct arguments depending on arguments passed to logAxiosErr. In unit test for logAxios you can not really test output of logger.error because logger.error is not a pure function, you should write separate unit test for logger.